next-themes attribute='class' not working in Next.js 14
I have used next-themes several times but this time the attribute='class' is not working, I tried to use everything that I could find over internet.
//environment
"next": "14.2.12",
"next-themes": "^0.3.0",

This is my current setup:
'use client';

import * as React from 'react';
import { Moon, Sun } from 'lucide-react';
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';

import {
  Button,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui';

export function ThemeSwitcher() {
  const { setTheme } = useTheme();
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) {
    return null;
  }

  function handleChange(theme: string) {
    setTheme(theme);
    // document.documentElement.className = theme;
  }

  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          className="md:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-white/80"
          variant="outline"
          size="icon-sm"
        >
          <Sun className="h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rotate-0 scale-100 transition-all dark:-rotate-90 dark:scale-0" />
          <Moon className="absolute h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rotate-90 scale-0 transition-all dark:rotate-0 dark:scale-100" />
          <span className="sr-only">Toggle theme</span>
        </Button>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleChange('light')}>
          Light
        </DropdownMenuItem>
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleChange('dark')}>
          Dark
        </DropdownMenuItem>
        <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => handleChange('system')}>
          System
        </DropdownMenuItem>
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}

I have tried to change the class by using document but on page refresh the theme is reset to default.
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';

interface ThemeProps {
  readonly children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const Theme: React.FC<ThemeProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider
      attribute="class"
      defaultTheme="light"
      enableSystem
      disableTransitionOnChange
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export { Theme };

All the other attributes like data-theme and color-scheme are getting updated, but I want to use class to change themes :/
In my diagnosis, the attribute is not working at all, I tried to change it to data-mode, class but it just keeps it as data-theme.
Let me know if I am doing something wrong here.
